# automatic constraints to a label inside xib swift

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, xib, nib

I have a nib file I created for a custom view to be loaded into a ViewController. The custom view has:
 .background image that fills the whole view (I'm using it as a background)
 .label inside that I need to be placed in a specific location based on the size of the background image.

I managed to resize the background image based on the size of the screen using AutoLayout in Storyboard. It can shrink with "Aspect Fit".
But I want to change the constraints of the label with the same ratio as the background image resized. Meaning, if the background image shrinks by half, I want the constraints of the label to change by half. This way, they will always show up at the same spot with respect to the image.

But the constraints I created in the storyboard for the label stay constant and I can not figure out how to manipulate the constraints for the label programatically.

here is the code for the custom class that defines the custom XIB view:
    import UIKit

@IBDesignable class TestView: UIView {

```
var view: UIView!
var nibName = "TestView"

@IBOutlet weak var backImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var upcomingLabel: UILabel!

@IBInspectable var Background: UIImage? {
    get {
        return backImage.image
    }
    set(Background) {
        backImage.image = Background
    }
}
@IBInspectable var maintenance: String? {
    get {
        return upcomingLabel.text
    }
    set(maintenance) {
        upcomingLabel.text = maintenance
    }
}

//MARK -    Implement both CustomView initializers: init(coder:) and init(frame:)
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    xibSetup()
}
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    xibSetup()
}

func xibSetup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds

    addSubview(view)
}
func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil) [0] as! UIView

    return view
}
}
```

And here is how I'm adding the view in the View controller:

```
import UIKit

class TestVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var customViewContainer: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let customView = TestView()
    customView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    customViewContainer.addSubview(customView)

    //Add constraint to the view
    let viewDictionary = ["custom": customView, "view": view]

    let constraintH = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[custom]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary)
    let constraintV = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[custom]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary)
    let constraintWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: customViewContainer, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let constraintHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: customViewContainer, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    view.addConstraints(constraintH as [AnyObject])
    view.addConstraints(constraintV as [AnyObject])
    view.addConstraint(constraintWidth)
    view.addConstraint(constraintHeight)

}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

I'm loosing my mind over this, help!

Comment: Why don't you _draw_ the image and _draw_ the text, together? That way you are in complete control of their size and placement.

Comment: I want to use the custom view as a template and be able to change the text in the label based on where I use the view. I made the label to be @IBInspectable.

Comment: So what's the hard part here? I don't understand what you're having trouble with.

Comment: I want, lets say the constraint from the bottom of the containing view to the bottom of the label, to change with the same proportion as the change to the height of the background image. So if the height of the background image changes to half, I want the constraint to change by half also.

Comment: Okay, that sounds fine. But only you know how the height of the background image changed - that is, you know the ratio between its original height and the height it is now. So, using that information, you can set the `constant` of that constraint accordingly. I ask again what part of that you're having trouble with.

Comment: Exactly that is what I'm having a problem with. I know I need to set the constraint based on the ratio of the background height, but how, in code or in IB can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You clearly know how to make a constraint, and you know what its `constant` is. So just set it to that value (whatever it may be).